# Checksum doesn't match: corrupted data.: while reading column `cid` at /opt/clickhouse//data/click

Tags: clickhouse

I am using clickhouse to store data, and I'm getting the following error while querying the column cid from the click table.

> Checksum doesn't match: corrupted data.

I don't have any replicate for now, any suggestions for recovery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error comes down to the fact the checksum of the `CityHash128` and the compressed data doesn't match and throws this exception in the [readCompressedData](https://github.com/yandex/ClickHouse/blob/master/dbms/src/IO/CompressedReadBufferBase.cpp#L98) function.

You can try to disable this check using the `disable_checksum` via the [disableChecksumming](https://github.com/yandex/ClickHouse/blob/master/dbms/src/IO/CompressedReadBufferBase.h#L53) method.

It could work, but a corrupted most probably means that something is wrong with your raw data and there is small chances for recovery unless you did backups.

Comment: Should I compile clickhouse source code by myself?  Do we have any other  options?

Comment: Corrupted data does not leave you a lot of options, yes that's what I would try before looking for backups

Comment: Disabling checksums is unlikely to help, because it means that compressed data is wrong, and decompression will fail.

Answer (score 2):

Usually, you will get data part name and column name in exception message.

You could locate specific data part, remove files related to that single column, and restart the server. You will lose (already corrupted) data for one column in one data part (it will be filled with default values on read), but all other data will remain.

Comment: Actually, this error message is all I got from the log. So there's no such thing like which data part.  And I cannot find out a way to remove specific data part.